# Schwarz distribution as a derivative of a continuous function - can such continuous functions be chosen to have the same support?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

The Schwarz theorem states that any function $f$ form the Schwarz class of tempered distributions $S'(\mathbb R^n)$ is a sum of derivatives from some continuous tempered distributions $g_\alpha\in С(\mathbb R^n)$:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|\le m}\partial^\alpha g_\alpha(x).
$$

I seem to rememeber even a variant with one function $g$.

Suppose now that $\mathrm{supp} f$  is in a halfspace $\{x_n\ge 0\}$. Can one take functions $g_\alpha$ s.t. their supoprt is also in the same halfspace?
Is the same true with a convex domain instead of a halfspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: my previous answer was wrong*, try with
$\delta(x,y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)=(\partial_x \partial_y)^2xy 1_{x>0}1_{y >0}$ where $xy 1_{x>0}1_{y >0}$ is not equal to a polynomial on the whole of $x >0$.

For half-spaces it works due to how we can construct $g$ such that $f=(\partial_{x_1}\ldots\partial_{x_n})^m g$:

Take $\psi\in C^\infty(\Bbb{R}), \psi=0$ on $t < -1$, $\psi=1$ on $t > 0$ and
let $J_l \phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(x+t e_l)dt, I_l\phi(x)=J_l\phi(x+\infty e_l)\psi(x_l)-J_l\phi(x)$.

Then given $f\in S'(\Bbb{R}^n)$ of order $m-1$ define the distribution $g\in S'(\Bbb{R}^n)$ by $$\forall  \phi \in S(\Bbb{R}^n) ,\qquad \langle g,\phi \rangle=\langle f,(I_1\ldots I_n)^m \phi \rangle$$

Comment: Thank you. In the light of your answer does the following reasoning 
 holds? Let $(x,a)=b$ be a support plane for a convex closed set $A$ and $A$ lies in the half-space $H=\{(x,a)>b\}$. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are polinomials for two such half-spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$, then they have to coincide on $H_1\cap H_2$. Therefore, if $\mathbb R^n\backslash A$ is connected then $g$ is equal to one polynomial $P$ on $\mathbb R^n\backslash A$ and $\mathrm{supp}  (f-P)\subset $A$.

Comment: Continued. And if  $\mathbb R^n\backslash A$ is not connected, like a segment on the line or an infinite strip on the plane, there are two such polynomials. Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: @Andrew There is something wrong is my answer, try with 
$\delta(x,y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)=(\partial_x \partial_y)^2xy 1_{x>0}1_{y >0}$ where $xy 1_{x>0}1_{y >0}$ is not equal to a polynomial on the whole of $x >0$.

Comment: Sorry, have in the latest edit the case of a half-space been proved or the counterexample shows that it's not true?

Comment: The polynomial argument was wrong, the $\langle g,\phi \rangle=\langle f,(I_1\ldots I_n)^m \phi \rangle$ argument is right. The point of $I_j$ is that $I_j\partial_{x_j}\phi = \phi$. But $\partial_{x_j} I_j \phi$ doesn't have to be $=\phi$. Then you need to prove that $f$ has finite order and to make clear what it means to show that $g$ is in $C^0(\Bbb{R}^n)$. By construction it is supported on an half-plane if $f$ is.

Comment: I'm trying tio understand the proof, all variables seem to appear symmetrically. Does this construction holds for all half-spaces   $\{x_i>0\}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$?